# create folder in php using a variable in path

Tags: php

i am a newbie in the field of web development, i am trying to create a folder using php's `mkdir()` command...

when i use...

```
mkdir("somefolder");
```

it works...

i had tried

```
mkdir("/somefolder/".$id."/photos");
```

but it won't work....i think i am doing it wrong how do i do this...

well the `$id` is coming from the database so that folder for each user will be created

Any help will be greatly appriciated...

thank you in advance...

**EDIT**

```
mkdir($id);
```

does creates a folder but above mentioned doesn't....

if somefolder is already there.. then mkdir won't work....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this purpose recursive parameter needs to be true...

`mkdir("/somefolder/$id/photos",0777,true)`

Answer (score 1):

> $path = "/somefolder/$id/photos";
>
> if (!file_exists( $path ) mkdir($path);
>
> else
>
> throw new Exception($path." file already exist");

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes around $id

```
mkdir("/somefolder/$id/photos");
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is incorrect:

```
mkdir("/somefolder/'$id'/photos");
```

Instead it should be

```
mkdir("/somefolder/".$id."/photos");
```

or

```
mkdir("/somefolder/$id/photos");
```

Make sure that your www-data user (or whichever user your script runs under) has the rights to create folders in /somefolder (`chown www-data /somefolder`)

and please remember to check that $id has the correct format before to avoid access to other directories with `$id = "../.."`

You could use

```
if(!is_numeric($id)) {
    /* do something */
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply Eric, if $id is numeric... then is it possible to create folder...

Comment: if it doesn't work give the rights to the www-data user or which ever user your server runs under. chown www-data /somefolder/

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with your absolute/relative path. Try removing the first slash. mkdir("somefolder/$id/photos")